# Java Client for sending bitcoin transactions

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency

The intention of this question is to understand what client sdks are available for programmers so that they can create cryptocurrency wallets and send transactions for the cryptocurrency.

I want to create a desktop application for myself that will store all my cryptocurrencies. I have several that I have bought. What kind of sdks exist for programmers to create wallets for cryptocurrencies, sending transactions, and getting information about network state? Will I need to use a different client for each cryptocurrency or is it possible to reuse implementations for scenarios such as - all tokens that run on ethereum or all tokens that were created from forking bitcoin?

I'd like to create wallets and make transactions for the following coins:

Bitcoin, Bitcoin Cash, Zcash, Dash, Litecoin - These are all Bitcoin based blockchains.

Ethereum, Monero, Tron, and 0x.

Comment: This is rather vague. Can you give more details of the features that you require? Please read [ask]. Welcome aboard; we really want to help you. the more that you help us, by giving us lots of details, the more that we can find a good answer for you.

Comment: I've added more details. Please let me know if I need to be more precise. I feel I have mentioned exactly what I am trying to understand.

Comment: That might much depend on the crypto currencies you wish to handle. Some of them work very much the same (or at least closely comparable) way, others might differ a lot. So maybe you include what currencies *must* be supported, and which would be considered "nice to have" (but not essential)? Not that I'm really familiar with the topic, but it might help those who are.

Comment: For instance, there is a proposal on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) for a site for Iota, which is a cryptocurrency which does not use blockchain. I  imagine that would have a rather different API

Comment: @Mawg I have added the specific coins. Is this the right place for a question like this or is there a better forum for this question? I feel like this is a StackOverflow question, but the community down voted this when I asked it there.

Comment: Good edit (+1). This is the correct place, I think, since it is a software recommendation question. For S.O, you need to 1) publish code, 2) say what it ought to do, 3) say what it is doing wrongly, so this is not a good fit there. There might be some crypto sites on S.E, I din't check. I know that there are some which have bene proposed on Area 51 - you should probably pop over there & register interest, to help them become full fledged SE sites